# ASP.NET CORE 3.0 Jquery Ajax request success is not executing sometimes in the same view

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

This is my view, ajax request and the controller respectively. The problem is when I save something, sometime it hits the success method in the ajax request and sometimes not.

> View

```
        <form id="myForm">
        <div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <label asp-for="RoleName" class="control-label"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-10">
                    <input asp-for="RoleName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="RoleName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div>
                        <button value="Index" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Save !"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

> Ajax request

```
        $("#btnSave").click(function () {

        debugger;

        var RoleObj = { RoleName: $('#RoleName').val() };

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "MasterRoles")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(RoleObj),
            headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() }
        }).done(function (response) {
            alert('Success');
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert('Error');
        });
    });
```

This is the controller which is invoked in the post method. Data is posting the only problem is that return values in getting in the success sometimes but not all the time

```
      [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Index([Bind("RoleName")] [FromBody] MasterRole masterRole)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(masterRole);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return Json(new { status = "1", roleList });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { status = "2", roleList });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { status = "2" });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your click function being called? If you do a `console.log("Button clicked")` inside, do you see this being logged? Also, if you include the code as text, this will help people adjust it with you more easily 

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with it but your button HTML is missing a closing brace. `<button value="Index" id="btnSave" </button>` should be `<button value="Index" id="btnSave"></button>`

Comment: Below your post helped me. Thank you @timothyclifford.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a suspicion your form is being submitted on button click which is why you sometimes don't see the ajax function being called.

You need to ignore the default mouse click on the button as this will submit the form:

```
$("#btnSave").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  debugger;
  var RoleObj = { RoleName: $("#RoleName").val() };
  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: '@Url.Action("Index", "MasterRoles")',
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(RoleObj),
    headers: {
      RequestVerificationToken: $(
        'input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]'
      ).val(),
    },
  })
    .done(function (response) {
      alert("Success");
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert("Error");
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that line did the trick. Thank you very much @timothyclifford 

Comment: Happy to hear @TharinduRukshan!